# What is the easiest way to display the contents of an ArrayList of Objects in a JTable?

Tags: jtable

I have an ArrayList of Track objects.
Each Track object has the following fields (all Strings):

url, title, creator, album, genre, composer

I want to display these tracks in a JTable, with each row being an instance of a Track object, and each column containing one of the properties of a Track object.

How can I display this data using a JTable? I've used an AbstractTableModel that implements the getValueAt() method correctly. Still, I dont see anything on the screen.

Or is it easier just to use arrays?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to add contents to display on a [`JTable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), one uses the [`TableModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) to add items to display.

One of a way to add a row of data to the `DefaultTableModel` is by using the [`addRow`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.lang.Object[])) method which will take an array of `Object`s that represents the objects in the row. Since there are no methods to directly add contents from an `ArrayList`, one can create an array of `Object`s by accessing the contents of the `ArrayList`.

The following example uses a `KeyValuePair` class which is a holder for data (similar to your `Track` class), which will be used to populate a [`DefaultTableModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) to display a table as a `JTable`:

```
class KeyValuePair
{
    public String key;
    public String value;

    public KeyValuePair(String k, String v)
    {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }
}

// ArrayList containing the data to display in the table.
ArrayList<KeyValuePair> list = new ArrayList<KeyValuePair>();
list.add(new KeyValuePair("Foo1", "Bar1"));
list.add(new KeyValuePair("Foo2", "Bar2"));
list.add(new KeyValuePair("Foo3", "Bar3"));

// Instantiate JTable and DefaultTableModel, and set it as the
// TableModel for the JTable.
JTable table = new JTable();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
table.setModel(model);
model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Key", "Value"});

// Populate the JTable (TableModel) with data from ArrayList
for (KeyValuePair p : list)
{
    model.addRow(new String[] {p.key, p.value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

then, the problem i have is that i cant see the problem at all.
here's the code i've used to make the interface:

```
public Interface(){

    setSize(1024, 768);
    setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(new MenuBar());//simple JMenuBar implementation

    table= new JTable();
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(jsp);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

after this code is executed, i have code in another class that does this many times:

```
((DefaultTableModel)mainInterface.table.getModel()).addRow(
new String[] {t.location,t.title,t.creator,t.album,t.genre,t.composer});
```

t is a Track object by the way.