# gets a output as [Ljava.lang.Object;@1d4481

Tags: java

i am trying to print set of months and dates to a colum of a table.. it shows {Ljava.lang.Object;@1d4481 eror.. but when i try to print days to the rows it works fine.. i searched stackover thread and found similar qustion also, it says object type something..
here is my table properties

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvGaR.gif)

here is my code

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //System.out.println("The current date is : " + calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("The current date is : " + calendar.getTime()); 

    calendar.set(1995, 10, 2);
    for(int i=0; i<2 ; i=i+1){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    //System.out.println(" Dates later: " + calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println(" Dates later: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));

    //System.out.println(" Dates later: " + Arrays.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).toArray())+"/"+Arrays.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE).toArray()));


    SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = dFormat.format(jDateChooser1.getDate()); 
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    //model.addRow(new Object[]{calendar});

     //model.addRow(new Object[]{calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)});  
     model.addColumn(new Object[]{calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)});
    }
```

Comment: i tried it in several ways... exsisting solution dosent work for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can try by putting as a row like : model.addRow(); and by this method pass the String array with all column values.

Please refer the link: [What is the easiest way to display the contents of an ArrayList of Objects in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623690/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-display-the-contents-of-an-arraylist-of-objects-in-a)

Comment: no i'm trying to print date and month value to colum vice.(like topics of each coloum) not all value to a single colum thats why i use  model.addColumn() function....

Comment: You should be able to do by following way: model.addRow(new Object[]{calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)}); but looks like you are printing object. Could you please also provide the screenshot of the screen how does it look like?

Comment: model.addRow() works fine... i need to do using model.addColumn()  function arrording to my requirement

Comment: model.addRow() works fine... i need to do using model.addColumn()  function arrording to my requirement